# Perform standard Save Button with X++

Tags: axapta, x++

I have custom code that require user to save the journal [image]when journal is created, so that the voucher number is removed from number sequence[image]. However I would like to write it in my code so that when the user click the button to run my code, it will save the journal to remove the voucher number from number sequence. Is there any code that allow us to save the Journal?

Comment: Have you tried calling the ```write``` method of the data source?

Comment: tried for both `LedgerJournalTable ` and `LedgerjournalTrans `, but non of them remove number sequence

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for FH-Inway To perform the save in Journal, the  `write`  method need to call with Data Source. EG: if the table for the form is `LedgerJournalTrans` the save function must be perform by using `LedgerJournalTrans_DS.write`. These are reserve keys for table data source hence it should apply for any tables.